# Set dynamic headers in axios from an ExpressJS app

Tags: javascript, express, axios

I have a requirement where I need to set a `Request-Id` header with each axios request. This header's value gets dynamically generated by another express middleware.

Now I can do :

```
axios.get(url, headers: {'Request-Id': req.requestId});
```

But I'd like to move this abstraction someplace common, so that this can be reused everywhere. I came up with a custom express middleware :

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.fetch = axios;
  req.fetch.defaults.headers.common['Request-Id'] = req.requestId;
  next();
})
```

Now I can use `req.fetch` in any route without having to set the header individually, but is this a recommended approach ?
It would be helpful if someone could explain if this approach has any pitfalls, or a better solution.

Comment: In javascript Objects are passed by reference and you are using same object **axios** for all the requests through your middleware now **req.fetch.defaults.headers.common['Request-Id']** will be set to the axios object which will be commonly shared for all the requests, so you may end up using one's requsetId into another.

Comment: Yes. I would ensure that only `req.fetch` is used everywhere else. But for the above problem statement, I can use `axios.create()` to create a specific instannce so that global object is unmodified.

Comment: Also, I would like to know of any possible race conditions in Express, which can result in the wrong / stale `Request-Id` being passed to the route.

Answer (score 1):

This does look fine to me right now.

You could use some config file as well to let the server consume or not your the middleware you just wrote :)

Maybe some other people might tell us their thoughts about it

Comment: I would like to know of any possible race conditions in Express, which can result in the wrong / stale `Request-Id` being passed to the route. 
Would there be a case where two simultaneous requests can end up using the wrong `Request-Id`s ?

Comment: As far as I know there shouldn't be race conditions, Express should handle your requests fine. At least, until you're not exceeding the limit of requests that Express can handle.